# Retrieve proper path for dynamic image src assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

I understand that there are similar questions out there, but none of them seem to work properly for me. I have a slider and an image. When I change the value of the slider, I want the image to change as well. Here are the relevant pieces of javascript:

```
 var imageArray = ['face0.png',
'face1.png',
'face1.png',
'face2.png',
'face2.png',
'face3.png',
'face3.png',
'face4.png',
'face4.png',
'face5.png',
'face5.png'];

function sliderValueChange(value) {
    //$('#painScaleImage').attr('src', '~/Content/' + imageArray[value]); ***gets wrong path
    //$('#painScaleImage').src('~/Content/' + imageArray[value]); ***jQuery has no method called .src()
    //document.getElementById('painScaleImage').src = '~/Content/' + imageArray[value]; ***gets wrong path
    //these are commented out because they all failed to work
}
```

My images are located in my project under Content/face0.png, Content/face1.png, etc. My Views are located in Views/Home/view.cshtml. The problem is that when I called the `$(...).attr()` and `document.getElementById(...).src` functions, the browser looked for the images under /Home/~/Content/face0.png instead of looking under Content/face0.png. The reason I assumed I could use ~/Content/face0.png is because if I were to declare the images in html, this would get the image in the right place `<img src="~/Content/face0.png" />`. How can I properly achieve what I am trying to do? What is going wrong?

Comment: using root-relative paths (almost) always works

Comment: how would you go about doing that? The problem is that I need to go up a folder-level. (I have my main project folder, inside of which I have my Content folder and my Views folder. So I need to go up a folder level to get to my images, which I don't know how to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, root relative paths were the correct answer for my solution.
(start the path with a `/`).